# Mysql time shifed replication

Tags: mysql, replication

We got a system with a Mysql database and a replication on a slave database.
We got huge uploads, which will do major changes to the master database. We want to keep the slave database the old version before the changes for a certain while.

Is it possible to set up the replication update to a certain time shift?

Comment: Sure, just schedule START SLAVE and STOP SLAVE at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 1):

As EJP say you can work manually using the stop/start slave, so you can stop replication using:

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
```

than resume when your checks are finished using:

```
mysql> START SLAVE;
```

Alternatively you can manage the delay of a replica using the **[MySQL Delayed Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html)**, note that this feature is available only on 5.6.x + MySQL version.

I think that a good idea where to start (but there are many configuration for your scenario) is to have 2 node attached in replica, one standard replica and one delayed replica:

```
Master
`--- Standard Replica
`--- Delayed Replica
```

In this configuration you have all the advantages in case of a master crash(promoting the standard replication) and all the advantages for checking your "past" :) and/or a point in time recovery